# How to re-direct to a page on website logout.?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, logout

First let me explain the scenario.

There are 2 websites, website-A and website-B. Both websites are hosted in different domains.

- User is able to login to website-B's homepage through website-A login page. This means that the user is now in complete control of website-B's functionalities.
- On successful logout in website-B, the user is re-directed to the homepage of website-B (which is the right behaviour).

My question starts here.

Is there a possible way to ensure that the user is re-directed to website-A's login page on successful logout in website-B rather than re-directing to website-B's login page?

If this is possible, then please do guide me on how to proceed in this scenario.

Thanks in advance !!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using forms authentication, you can create a logout method like :

```
private void Logout()
{
  Session.Abandon();
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage` will redirect to the [LoginUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl.aspx).

Comment: I don't have server side access of website-B (third party website). I was success in only auto-login of website-B through website-A. Hence I cannot control the logout mechanism directly through server side code. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: if you cannot implement a logout mechanism on website 2, then you cannot redirect from that website.you can only come back to website 1 and logout(your implementation) which seems pretty crazy :-D sorry you cannot.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Yes, I too had the same thought as per the web application concepts. But, I just wanted to re-check whether I'm missing any!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use `Response.Redirect("url");`

Comment: I cannot use Response.Redirect("url"), as I cannot control the logout flow implementation in website-B, which is a third party website. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: like Srinivas said if you cant access website B then you cant redirect the logout url to website A